# Problema com link interno utilizando JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia, tarde ou noite para todos.
Estou tendo uma dificuldade tentando fazer um menu de navegação com link interna utilizando JavaScript puro.

O problema é que provavelmente eu estou tento é que não estou conseguindo captar os dados do usuário, porém não sei oque está errado, na ferramenta do desenvolvedor do browser (chrome) diz que o nodeList[0] sendo que deveria ser [3]. Os "ids" dos links estão adicionados

```js
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu a');

menuItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', scrollToIdOnClick);
})

function getScrollTopByHref(element) {
  const id = element.getAttribute('href');
  return document.querySelector(id).offsetTop;
}

function scrollToIdOnClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const to = getScrollTopByHref(event.target) - 150;
  scrollToPosition(to);
}

function scrollToPosition(to) {
  window.scroll({
    top: to,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#menu">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#quemSomos">Quem Somos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#produtos">Nossos Produtos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#contato">Contato</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o querySelectorAll teria que ser assim:

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('a.menu');
```

Comment: Boa noite Rafael, eu tentei mudar como vc orientou porém o nodeList continua zerado invés de estar como [3]

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não entendi o seu real problema. Mas o código que postou não irá funcionar.

Pois o erro nesse código está nessas duas linhas

```
 const id = element.getAttribute('href');
 return document.querySelector(id).offsetTop;
```

Primeira linha retorna pra variavel o href que vc clicou, por exemplo "#menu"

Depois você está tentando fazer document.querySelector("#menu"), mas não existe esse id no html, então ele nao acha o offsetTop.

Você precisa adicionar ids nos links... id="menu", id="quemSomos" e assim por diante

Comment: Boa note Julio os Ids estão devidamente colados, eu estou suspeitando que não estou conseguindo captar os dados porque o nodeList está zerado sendo que deveria estar [3]. Mas obrigado pela ajuda!!